# How to create a custom SKAction in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

The idea is that I am creating blocks that are falling out of the sky.

To do this I need an custom action that does four things:

1. Create an node with my block class
2. Set the position of that node
3. add the node to the scene
4. after an delay go to point one

I am wondering if you actually can create a `SKAction.customActionWithDuration` to do this things.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method creates an `SKAction` that should fit your needs.

```
func buildAction() -> SKAction {
    return SKAction.runBlock {
        // 1. Create a node: replace this line to use your Block class
        let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)

        // 2. Set the position of that node
        node.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300)

        // 3. add the node to the scene
        self.addChild(node)

        // 4. after a delay go to point one
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0), duration: 1)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, move])
        node.runAction(sequence)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @appsYourLife.
I've made a couple of changes below:

1. I've adjusted for swift 3
2. I've added a parameter called parent so you can either use `buildAction(parent: self)` or if you want to attach the node to some otherNode you can use `buildAction(parent: otherNode)`

   ```
   func buildAction(parent: SKNode) -> SKAction {
     return SKAction.run {

     // 1. Create a node: replace this line to use your Block class
     let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
     // 2. Set the position of that node
     node.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300)

     // 3. add the node to the scene
     parent.addChild(node)

     // 4. after a delay go to point one
     let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
     let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0), duration: 1)
     let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, move])
     node.run(sequence)
    }
   }
   ```